# dynamodb java sdk compare two attributes

Tags: conditional-statements, amazon-dynamodb

Can i add condition where i will say if attribute one is equal to attribute two then return it in the result or what will be a logic in the application level to do this?

I need somehow this filtering and pagination which i'm going to use lastKey bla bla ...

I don't know if dynamodb using java sdk or any other sdk support this to compare two attributes to retrieve data.

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
    .withTableName(tableName)
    .withIndexName(indexName)
    .withLimit(maxResult)
    .withExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey)
    .withKeyConditions(keyConditions)
    .withScanIndexForward(false);
    if(attributesToget == null) {
        queryRequest = queryRequest.withSelect(Select.ALL_ATTRIBUTES);
    } else {
        queryRequest = queryRequest.withSelect(Select.SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES)
                .withAttributesToGet(attributesToget);
    }
    return queryRequest;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't I compare two different attributes in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993519/cant-i-compare-two-different-attributes-in-dynamodb)